# jquery how do I get my h1 to reappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the code I'm working with:

```
$("#nav_list a").click(function() {
    $("h1:gt(0)").hide();
    $("article").hide();
    var href_value = $(this).attr("href");
    $("h1:has(href_value)").show();
});
```

Why I am confused is because if I replace the last line with this line it works:

```
$("h1:has(#test)").show();
```

And if I test my variable with:

```
alert(href_value);
```

The output is:

```
#test
```

So if I'm trying to get `#test` and thats why my variable contains why does it not work?

Comment: JavaScript does not automatically translate Strings into variable values.

Comment: The `:has()` pseudo-selector usually accepts any jQuery selector `a` or `a[href$=pdf]`. However, `href_value` is not a selector but an attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate the `href_value` value to the selector:

```
$("h1:has(" + href_value + ")").show();
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked but I'm not sure what using those +'s did?

Comment: @JacobPeterson Because `href_value` is a variable. It needed to be concatenated and evaluated rather than being interpreted literally as part of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead :

```
$("h1:has("+href_value+")").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate a string with a variable and also use specify the attribute like so:

```
$('h1:has(a[href="' + href_value + '"])').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to concatenate a string with a variable.

```
$("#nav_list a").click(function() {
    $("h1:gt(0)").hide();
    $("article").hide();
    var href_value = $(this).attr("href");
    $("hi:has("+ has_value +")").show();
});
```